# Semantic UI - form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, semantic-ui

I have a problem with validation optional inputs.

I need this:
if (is input `visible => validate` it)
else ignore it

Problem is ... I don't know, how can I change value optional: true to optional: false in Semantic UI form rules.

**In  `$(document).ready(function() {})`;**

```
$('#addForm')
    .form({
        fields: {
            im_image: {
                identifier: 'im_image',
                rules: [
                    {
                        type: 'empty',
                        prompt: 'Please select image'
                    }
                ]
            },
            im_video: {
                identifier: 'im_video',
                optional: true,
                rules: [
                    {
                        type: 'empty',
                        prompt: 'Please enter video URL'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'url',
                        prompt: 'Please enter valid URL adress'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'contains[youtube]',
                        prompt: 'Please enter valid Youtube URL'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        inline: true,
        on: 'blur'
    });
```

Comment: try `optional: $("#im_video").is(":visible")`

Comment: Not working, because $('#addForm') is in document ready.

Comment: make it as a function try `optional: function(){$("#im_video").is(":visible")}`

Comment: same result ... not working

Comment: sorry a small change  `optional: function(){return $("#im_video").is(":visible");}` the value was not returned

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2hLrm13/5/